# Defining master nodes in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I define my master nodes in **elasticsearch.yml** with below code

```
node.master: true
node.data: true
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["...","...", "..."...]
```

I have 10 nodes and I set 6 of them as master.

When I check from kibana devtools with below code:

```
GET /_cat/nodes?v=
```

I see all nodes but just one of them is master. Why the other 5 didn't set ? Can someone answer ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a node as master in the configuration using `node.master: true` you are actually saying that this node is *master eligible*, it will be part of the voting process with the other *master eligible* nodes in the cluster and in the end only **one** node will be elected as the master node of the cluster.

The return of `_cat/nodes` is correct, only **one** node will appear as master, if this node fail for some reason, the other five eligible nodes in your cluster will start another voting process to choose the new master of the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I ve accepted your answer. If you like the question, feel free to upvote :)